# How to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Tags: uicollectionview

This is the first time I use UICollectionView and it is quite interesting, but I hit the following problem. Can anyone help me clarify what is happening ?

With the following code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(280.0,36.0);
}
```

I have this display:

[image]

Obviously I need a higher space to display the cell reading "Nous sommes" because it has a second line now invisible.
Since this is the fifth line I use the following code (expecting to solve the problem):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(280.0,indexPath.row!=4?36.0:72.0);
}
```

But here is the result:

[image]

Returning a size with a larger height causes the cell to extent horizontally (which I do not want) while still giving the space (vertically) without using it.
I am missing something. Please explain if you can.

Comment: related .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790601/uikit-dynamics-exactly-like-iphone-text-messages-ready-solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume the blue rectangle is a subview of the cell (because it is less than your cell width of 280 in the first example). The problem is likely that you need to set your struts & springs (or constraints if you're using Auto Layout) such that your subviews resize the way you want when the cell gets resized. Looking at your layout, I think you want to specify fixed width and flexible height (or the Auto Layout equivalent).

If you're still stuck, please post details about your struts & springs (or Auto Layout constraints).

Comment: Yes the blue rectangle is indeed a subview of the cell.
I do not use Auto Layout and playing with struts & springs doesn't seem to have much effect. Which is normal (I suppose) since I programmatically recompute the size according to the text inside. Anyway I was able to solve this problem, it was due my being unaware of what was computed first when making a comparison.
Now I notice that I always get one cell per row, even if the cells are narrow enough to fit two in a row.
According to what I can see browsing the net, that does not seem to be right. But what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Huh. You didn't mention you were programmatically computing the size of the blue rectangle. I'd think the reason you're getting one cell per row is because according to the code you posted, you're always returning a cell width of 280, which is more than half the width of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. Anyway I realized I would not be able to do what I wanted using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. So I went to using UICollectionViewLayout and I am on my way to get things to work.

Comment: 140 probably just want enough. Looks like you've got about 20px on each side. Combine that with two 140px cells and you're at 320px. And if you've got the default 10px cell spacing, you're at 330px. Anyway...